# Linked Server in View vs calling View Remotely from Another Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, linked-server, openquery

I have some views used by an app which contain loads of references to a single other server, as a linked server (I'll call the local server "Target" and the remote server "Source")- a bit like this:

```
SELECT
    --[Columns]
FROM
            [Source].[s_db].[dbo].[a_table] A
INNER JOIN  [Source].[s_db].[dbo].[b_table] B   ON A.[Id]  = B.[Id] 
LEFT JOIN   [Source].[s_db].[dbo].[c_table] C   ON B.[Id2] = C.[Id] 
INNER JOIN  [Source].[s_db].[dbo].[d_table] D   ON C.[Id2] = D.[Id]
INNER JOIN  [Source].[s_db].[dbo].[e_table] E   ON D.[Id2] = E.[Id]
---- and so on
```

I hate these views and I want to know whether I'm justified or just prejudiced.

Is there a better way to write these (performance, neatness, ability to publish to a different server etc)?

So far,  my thoughts have been:

- Make a companion database to the source [Source_Companion], on the
  remote server
- Recreate the view in the [Source_Companion] database,
  referencing the [Source] database
- Create a View in the [Target] database
- Call the view in the [Source] database using openquery, with a sensibly named linked server. `Create view [vw] as select * from openquery([Source],'SELECT * FROM vw') as t`

This seems like a lot of work and I'm worried that I'm just letting my prejudice get the better of me. Do you think I will see any benefit from these changes? Maybe there is something else I should be doing to make these views better or maybe (god forbid) I should just suck it up and move on - what's your opinion? It's not like they are performing so badly as to cause comment right now, but I want things to be as good and tidy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example suggests all tables used in the query reside on one server. Therefor, creating the view on that server seems like a good and legit option as all joining and stuff can be done locally on one server - and only the result set needs to be transferred over the linked server compared to the current state you have.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought about doing that, but... Do you think I will see any benefit from these changes?

Comment: It depends on several things, but possibly your current setup could result in entire tables that you join-in being transferred temporarily to the server hosting the view. Could also depends on versions of SQL Server, linked server configuration and permissions of the user(s) making the linked server connection when it comes the possibility to use statistics etc on the server hosting the data. Bottom line is, yes you could potentially see a huge benefit but it could potentially also make a very small difference. You will have to test it.

Comment: yeah, fair point. I guess I go for what I think is good practice and then deal with the consequences.